# call script based on onedit / google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-installable-triggers

I'm looking to launch a script based on an edit on a specific sheet/cell.

Lets say when Sheet 'Scripts' cell A1 = 'Phone Script'

This function launches:

```
   var formTitle = 'Phone Script';
   var formID = 'My Form ID';
   var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
   var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();
   var htmlApp = HtmlService
   .createHtmlOutput('<script>location.href = "' + formUrl + '"</script>')
   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
   .setTitle(formTitle)
   .setWidth(500) 
   .setHeight(450);
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(htmlApp);`
```

I originally had this assigned to a button but I'd like to move off of that.

Comment: Here was my solution.  On edit of cell C1 it launches function emailandsave850

     function onEditSend850(e) {
     if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'C1' || e.value !== 'Send 850') 
     return;
     emailandsave850()
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function onEditSend850(e) {
 if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'C1' || e.value !== 'Send 850') return;
 emailandsave850()
 }
```

on edit trigger, when c1 reads Send 850 it will run function emailandsave850